# What's the library in Python 3 that uses append

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is embarrassing but I can't have this simplified piece of code to work.

```
big = {}
small = [ 10, 20, 30 ]

print (small)
print (big.append(small))
```

The given error is:

```
print (big.append(small))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no> attribute 'append'
```

I guess that "append" uses a library but I can't find that anywhere.
What's the solution for this error?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? What do you expect to happend when you call `big.append(small)`?

Comment: I intend to populate the big array with the small array. The code was simplified, but basically the intention is that, populating the big array with the data from small arrays

Comment: You probably are talking about list objects, not arrays (there is a difference, in Python). But `big` is a *dictionary*, not a list.

Comment: If you did want to add it to a dictionary, you could do `big.update(small)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.append()` is a method on *list* objects, not on dictionaries.

To add a value to a dictionary, you need to assign it to a key:

```
big['small'] = small
```

There is no Python library that lets you use `.append()` on a dictionary.

If `big` is meant to be a *list* as well, then *make* it a list:

```
>>> big = []
>>> small = [10, 20, 30]
>>> big.append(small)
>>> big
[[10, 20, 30]]
```

but note that `list.append()` alters the list in-place, and returns `None`; trying to print the return value of `big.append(small)` will not print the new list.

Also note that `list.append()` will append the `small` list as *one* value, resulting in a nested list. If you wanted to add the *elements* of `small` to `big`, use `list.extend()`:

```
>>> big = []
>>> small = [10, 20, 30]
>>> big.append(small)
>>> big
[10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: Worked like a sharm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is sample**

for example

symbols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's','t','u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

def ID_Generetor():
ID = ""
for i in range(0,15):
data = random.choice(symbols)
⤵️
ID += data
print(ID)

I hope you understand

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters and format your code.